# Javascript - can't extract string?

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the image url http://www.bornholmstidende.dk/images/logo.gif.
I have the html code in a string, so I can't use `document.getMeta`.

Here is the HTML code I have:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Kunst og hverdag" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Foredraget er det første af fem, der holdes på Bornholms Kunstmuseum" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.bornholmstidende.dk/?Id=26502" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.bornholmstidende.dk/images/logo.gif" />
```

Comment: How about using [.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) to find the last occurrence of "content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getMetaImage(){
  var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
  for(var i=0;mLen=metas.length;i<mLen;i++){
    if(metas[i].getAttribute('property').toLowerCase() == 'og:image'){
      return metas[i].getAttribute('content');
    }
  }
  return null;//or empty string if you prefer
}
```

Comment: Thank you - just what i needed to know!

Comment: @Frederik Witte, How come solution with `document.getElementsByTagName` works for you if have the meta tags in string not in document?

Answer (score 3):

If you can use jQuery, you can use it to create a DOM fragment from your HTML string, target the node with selector and get the attribute:

```
$(your_meta_string).find('meta[property="og:image"').attr('content')
```

**EDIT:** If you can not use jQuery, use regular expression:

```
var match= /<meta property="og:image" content="(.*)" \/>/.exec(your_meta_string)
if (match) console.log(match[1])
```

The `match` will be `null` if not found and `Array` if found with `0` being the entire meta tag and `1` being only the value of `content` attribute.